# read in flex scanner failed, compiling with gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, flex-lexer, loader

After compilation of whole source, while linking I get this error:

`/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: read in flex scanner failed`

Any pointers what could be going wrong and where to look for it?

Comment: I got the same error message when the wrong path was being passed to the `-T` flag for the linker.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out i was passing wrong path to the file in g++ --version_script=*worng_path*

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a space after a comma when specifying linker arguments:
`-L. -Wl,-T, gcc_arm.ld`
resulted in

`read in flex scanner failed`

To fix, ensure there are no spaces around the commas:
`-L. -Wl,-T,gcc_arm.ld`